# Java Recursion is broken: Writing a sentence backwards

Tags: java, recursion

I need to extract a sentence from a file, write it backwards, and then output to a file. I have gotten the sentence to be extracted easily with my fromFile method and will have no problem outputting the sentence with my toFile method.

My current issue is recursion. Here is an example of what I want:

Original sentence: "This will be written backwards"

New Sentence: "backwards written be will This"

An easy solution would be to use arrays for this but I cannot do that. I know how the recursion works but I cannot seem to output the sentence word by word so I believe I have a logic issue. I have spent a few hours looking for it and then looking for examples online. I am at a loss as to what to do. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;
public class Recursion {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String output; //output to the second file

        System.out.println("Starting program...");
        System.out.println("\nFirst Line:");
        fromFile();
        
    }//end Main

    public static void writeBackward(String s)
    {
        String output; //holds the output
        String newString; //holds the new string
        if (s.length() < 1) //base case - no more characters in string
         {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Base Case is executed. Done.");
         }
         else
         {
            output = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "));
            output.trim();
            newString = s.substring(output.length());
            System.out.print(output + " ");
            writeBackward(newString);
         }
    }//end writeBackward

    public void toFile(String output)
 {
      try
      {
            String outPutFile = "input.txt";                //file name
            FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(outPutFile);
            BufferedWriter buffWrite = new BufferedWriter (fileWrite);
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (buffWrite);
            String outLine = output;
            outFile.print(outLine);
            outFile.println();
            outLine = "";
            //flush and close the output file
            buffWrite.flush ();
            buffWrite.close ();
        }//end try

        catch(IOException exception)
        {
              System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }//end catch

}//end toFile

 public static void fromFile()
 {
        try
        {
            String temp; //temporary string to be sent to recursion
            String inPutFile = "input.txt"; //file name
            String line = "";               //line of data read from file
            StringTokenizer inLine;            //tokenized string
            //open the input stream
            FileReader fRead = new FileReader(inPutFile);
            //buffer input stream one line at a time
            BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader (fRead);
            //Get data from file

            //read in the first line of the file
            line = bRead.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                //parse the new line using the comma as the delimiter
                temp = line;
                System.out.println("Debug temp: " + temp + "Debug line: " + line);
                writeBackward(temp);
                 //get the next line in the external file
                line = bRead.readLine();

            }//end while line not null

            //close the input file
            bRead.close ();

        }//end try

        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }//end catch

    }//end fromFile
}//end RecursionClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void writeBackward(String s) {
    String output = ""; // holds the output
    if (s.split(" ").length <= 1) // base case - no more characters in string
    {
        output += s;
        System.out.print(output + " ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Base Case is executed. Done.");
    } else {
        output = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
        s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(" "));
        output.trim();
        System.out.print(output + " ");
        writeBackward(s);
    }
}
```